# Solve DE: $y'' + y' = x$ by letting $p = y'$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve DE: $y'' + y' = x$ by letting $p = y'$.

Doesn't seem to work for exact equations or homogenous solutions.

Comment: Can you please add your work so we can see where things may have gone wrong?

Comment: The hint tells you to solve $p'+p=x$.

Comment: no problem with that part.

Comment: Without showing any of your work, no one can know what parts you have no problem with and what parts you need help on. Please update your question so that the nice people that would like to help you don't have to guess what you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

With factor $e^x$:
$$(e^xy')'=e^xy''+e^xy'=e^x(y''+y')=xe^x$$
then with integration
$$e^xy'=e^x(x-1)+C_1$$
or
$$y'=x-1+C_1e^{-x}$$
and finally
$$y=\dfrac12x^2-x-C_1e^{-x}+C_2$$